# wine msi installation issue - err:msidb, fixme:storage

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python, wine

I am trying to do stuff with vpython.

vpython.org suggests I do a wine installation and then try to install the vpython stuff as per the instruction mentioned [here](http://vpython.org/contents/download_linux.html)

But the issue is with wine when trying to install python itself. (Please note I cannot use my linux python for this). I am sharing the output of that operation:

```
$ wine msiexec /i python-2.7.9.amd64.msi /qn TARGETDIR=C:\Python27 ALLUSERS=1
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 1 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 2 out of range
err:msidb:get_tablecolumns column 3 out of range
```

What seems to be the problem? Fyi, I use an ubuntu 14.04 64-bit os

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a bug in wine 1.6: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wine1.6/+bug/1383214

A fix has been recently released.